# Is there a way to change the gesture that invokes Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, multi-touch

i use launchpad quite a lot, but find the 'finger & thumb' pinch rather awkward.

i never use mission control, and would love to use the 3 finger vertical swipe for launchpad instead of mission control.

in the trackpad section of system preferences there appears to be no way to swap these out, which seems rather limited to me.

Can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Launchpad & Dock and set a keyboard shortcut to Lauchpad.app.

[image: System Preferences]

- Use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) to set a custom gesture to activate the keystroke you've set before.